# How to get text between two Elements in DOM object?

Tags: java, html, dom, tags, jsoup

I'm using JSoup to parse this HTML content:

```
<div class="submitted">
    <strong><a title="View user profile." href="/user/1">user1</a></strong> 
    on 27/09/2011 - 15:17 
    <span class="via"><a href="/goto/002">www.google.com</a></span>
</div>
```

Which looks like this in web browser:

```
user1 on 27/09/2011 - 15:17 www.google.com
```

The username and the website can be parsed into variables using this:

```
String user    = content.getElementsByClass("submitted").first().getElementsByTag("strong").first().text(); 
String website = content.getElementsByClass("submitted").first().getElementsByClass("via").first().text();
```

But I'm unsure of how to get the "on 27/09/2011 -15:17" into a variable, if I use

```
String date = content.getElementsByClass("submitted").first().text();
```

It also contains username and the website???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always **remove** the `user` and the `website` elements like this (you can clone your `submitted` element if you do not want the remove actions to "damage" your document):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Document content = Jsoup.parse(
      "<div class=\"submitted\">" +
      "  <strong><a title=\"View user profile.\" href=\"/user/1\">user1</a></strong>" +
      "  on 27/09/2011 - 15:17 " + 
      "  <span class=\"via\"><a href=\"/goto/002\">www.google.com</a></span>" +
      "</div> ");

    // create a clone of the element so we do not destroy the original
    Element submitted = content.getElementsByClass("submitted").first().clone();

    // remove the elements that you do not need 
    submitted.getElementsByTag("strong").remove();
    submitted.getElementsByClass("via").remove();

    // print the result (demo)
    System.out.println(submitted.text());
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
on 27/09/2011 - 15:17
```

Answer (score 0):

You can then parse string that you get.

```
String str[] = contentString.split(" ");
```

Then you can construct the string you want like this:

```
String str = str[1] + " " + str[2] + " - " + str[4];
```

This will extract you the string you need.

Comment: username may contain space and cause problem though

Comment: Well you can get username and web into variable, then it is no problem to extract other data from given string write something like this: contentString.replace("username",""); and contentString.replace("web",""); this will delete username and web name from string, then you can trim string to delete spaces left before and after.

Answer (score 0):

Select the element before the text you wish to grab, then get its next sibling *node* (not element), which is a text node:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<div class=\"submitted\">" +
  "  <strong><a title=\"View user profile.\" href=\"/user/1\">user1</a></strong>" +
  "  on 27/09/2011 - 15:17 " +
  "  <span class=\"via\"><a href=\"/goto/002\">www.google.com</a></span>" +
  "</div> ");
String str = doc.select("strong").first().nextSibling().toString().trim();
System.out.println(str);
```

You can also ask an element for its child text nodes and index directly (though referencing the nodes by sibling is usually more robust than indexing):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(
            "<div class=\"submitted\">" +
  "  <strong><a title=\"View user profile.\" href=\"/user/1\">user1</a></strong>" +
  "  on 27/09/2011 - 15:17 " +
  "  <span class=\"via\"><a href=\"/goto/002\">www.google.com</a></span>" +
  "</div> ");
String str = doc.select("div").first().textNodes().get(1).text().trim();
System.out.println(str);
```